# how to pass the value of jquery UI slider to mysql database in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails

Hi I am having the following 3 fields.

1. questions
2. weightage
3. score

each question having the weightage and score. weightage is the total value. we can select our score out of weightage value. for example if a question having weightage value 10 means then we can select our score from 1 to 10 (out of weightage). here am using Jquery slider to select score. Here am having multiple questions with weightage and score. I cannot save the slider value in database because am using an array to store. really I do not how to pass more than one slider value to database using an array..please help me if anyone knows how to do this? thanks in advance

Comment: anyone please provide me some guidance to get rid from this problem?